# Event handlers in Paper.js

Tags: javascript, graphics, paperjs

I am new to Paper.js, and I was wondered by the event system, while reading tutorial.
Thats how event hanling described in [tutorial](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/interaction/mouse-tool-events/):

```
var path;
function onMouseDown(event) {
    // Create a path:
    path = new Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';
    // Add the mouse down position:
    path.add(event.point);
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    // Add the mouse up position:
    path.add(event.point);
}
```

So, its just functions in global namespace...
Eventually I have a few questions about it, and I didnt found anything on the internet on this:
- How to bind event handler to particular canvas?
- How to bind event handler to particular "object" (raster image, rectangle, etc)?
- How to bind multiple event handlers to something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind multiple event handlers using the attach() method (or its jQuery-style alias, on()). You can remove them with detach() or off(). Here's a modified example from [the event handling documentation](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#attach-type-function):

```
// Create a circle shaped path at the center of the view:
var path = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 25,
    fillColor: 'black'
});

var shiftPath = function() {
    this.position += new Point(15,15);
};

// When the mouse enters the item, set its fill color to red:
path.attach('mouseenter', function() {
    this.fillColor = 'red';
});

path.on('mouseenter', shiftPath);

// When the mouse leaves the item, set its fill color to black
// and remove the mover function:
path.on('mouseleave', function() {
    this.fillColor = 'black';
    path.detach('mouseenter', shiftPath);
});
```

If you want to set an event handler for all instances of a type of object, it's best to create a factory function, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865016/recommended-way-to-extend-classes-in-paper-js/18024582#18024582).

Comment: Alex, how would the last part of your answer translate in code? I would like to attach event handlers for mouseEnter, mouseleave for all the objects except rasters, in my Paper.js /JS project. How can I do that? The items are imported from SVG's so its kind of a mess to add handlers to each of the paths manually.

Comment: And how can we add an event to a shape when we use javascript directly via paper.js? ( we have to add tools manually  ... )

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Paperjs, but here is what I think:

> - How to bind event handler to particular canvas?

The scope is automatically associated to a canvas when you specify your canvas to a script:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" src="js/myScript.js" canvas="myCanvas"></script>
```

Each instruction of this script will be associated to this canvas.

> - How to bind event handler to particular "object" (raster image, rectangle, etc)?

Depending on is type each "object" have is sets of events handlers available.
The [reference page](http://paperjs.org/reference/) will give you all the events handlers for each type of objects.

> - How to bind multiple event handlers to something?

For example PathItem have a [click event](http://paperjs.org/reference/pathitem/#onclick) and a [double click event](http://paperjs.org/reference/pathitem/#ondoubleclick).

```
var path = new Path.Circle();

path.onClick = function(event) {
    this.fillColor = 'red';
}

path.onDoubleClick = function(event) {
    this.fillColor = 'green';
}
```

Comment: I meant two handlers for one event

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "two handlers for one event"?