# How to animate the drawing of a line or an arc in PaperJS based on a duration?

Tags: animation, paperjs

I have three questions:

- I have created an [animation](http://jsfiddle.net/Pancho/3JS29/) to draw a straight line. It works but I'm sure it's not the best way to do it. Someone can suggest some improvement to my code?

Pseudo code:

```
onFrame = function() {

  -Calculate % of the line that have been drawn
  -Find Point between two Points
  -Draw line until this new point
}
```

**[Here is my code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pancho/3JS29/)**

- My technique worked for a straight line but how could I do if I want to draw an [Arc](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#path-arc-object) based on a duration?
- What if I want to add an easing effect to the drawing?

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of adding segments to a path, I find it easier create a path
  out of two segments and move the last segment per frame. If you create a
  new `Point` from the difference of your end and start `Points`, you
  can easily calculate the position per frame based on your
  time-duration.
- As for an arc, it's easier to create a new one every frame. The
  `Path.Arc(from, through, to)` format works well here. Just rotate
  clones of your start `point` about your center `point` by
  `percent_completed / 2 * numberOfDegrees` and `percent_completed *
  numberOfDegrees` to get the `through` and `to` values per frame. If
  you want to create a full circle, make sure `numberOfDegrees` is
  slightly greater than 360. Otherwise `Arc()` may not find a proper
  solution.
- Your time-based percentage method works fine, but you need to account
  for when `percent_completed` ends too far before 1.
- If you want to do easing, modify `percent_completed` by an
  appropriate function. Search around for 'sigmoid easing'. For
  example:

  `percent_completed = Math.pow(percent_completed, .5);`

  This can be as intricate as you want to make it.
- Rather than check a boolean every frame, attach an `onFrame` handler
  on setup, and remove the handler when complete. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788760/event-handlers-in-paper-js/19797161) for more details.
- If you're using `paperscript` notation, you don't need to add the `paper` prefix to constructors.
- I'm not sure why you're including jQuery functions inside your paperscript either.

[Here's a jsFiddle demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/3JS29/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getLocationAt`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var point = path.getLocationAt(i);
    newPath.add(point);
}
```

(This is just a rough sketch, to explain my idea).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example of a circle following an arc](http://kennethfrederick.com/folio.js/FStepperExample.html), I'm using the interpolate function of my [folio.js](http://github.com/frederickk/folio.js) library, but the basics are.

```
// move path along an arc
path.position.x *= Math.cos(delta);
path.position.y *= -Math.sin(delta)*2;
```

check out the [source](http://kennethfrederick.com/folio.js/scripts/FStepperExample.js) to see more details on how it works