# Extending Three.js classes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to extend the Three.js Object3D class, but can't figure out how to do it.

There's this Stackoverflow question, which I've read, re-read and tried, but can't get it to work for me.

[Is there a way to extend a ThreeJS object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999155/is-there-a-way-to-extend-a-threejs-object)

Could anyone offer some specific code on how to get this going?  Here's what I have at the moment:

```
var MyObject3D = function() {
   THREE.Object3D.call(this);
   MyObject3D.prototype = new THREE.CubeGeometry();
   MyObject3D.prototype.constructor = MyObject3D;
}
```

And to create an instance:

```
var thing = new MyObject3D();
var testGeo = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10, 10, 10);
var testMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
var testMesh = new THREE.Mesh(testGeo, testMat);
thing.add(testMesh);
```

But calling the "add" method of the MyObject3D instance returns an error that "thing" has no method "add."

What's the deal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're setting the prototype to CubeGeometry, which has no add method. Based on the way you're trying to instantiate the object, it looks like you actually want your object to have the Mesh prototype.

Most likely you want something like this:

```
var MyObject3D = function() {
    // Run the Mesh constructor with the given arguments
    THREE.Mesh.apply(this, arguments);
};
// Make MyObject3D have the same methods as Mesh
MyObject3D.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);
// Make sure the right constructor gets called
MyObject3D.prototype.constructor = MyObject3D;
```

Then to instantiate it:

```
var testGeo = new THREE.CubeGeometry(20, 20, 20);
var testMat = new Three.MeshNormalMaterial();
var thing = new MyObject3D(testGeo, testMat);
```

Comment: Thank you!!  The CubeGeometry thing was just a copy/paste mistake when i created the question, but you still solved my problem :)   I was setting the new class's prototype inside the constructor function.  Moving it outside fixed it.  I'm curious though why that would make a difference.  (You may have noticed I'm still learning OO in Javascript.)

Comment: The prototype gets applied to an object instance before the constructor runs, so when you were setting MyObject3D.prototype in the constructor, that wouldn't take effect for the first object instantiated with that constructor. However after the constructor ran once, the prototype would have changed, so all future objects of that type would have prototypes that looked the way you wanted. (They'd all be slightly different though because you were instantiating a new object for each one!)

Comment: I actually kind of understand that, weirdly enough.  Thanks!!