# can't extend from THREE.js class

Tags: javascript, inheritance, three.js

I am very new to three.js and javascript so I am not entirely sure whether this is a three.js or javascript issue, but I am unable to inherit from the THREE.Mesh class in the right way and have my mesh displayed on the screen. For some reason I am not allowed to call the constructor new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); inside the constructor of my class. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

I read this post: [Extending Three.js classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043171/extending-three-js-classes)

and got it to work but I would like to use an actual class instead of this strange construct that is proposed there.

```
    class Icon extends THREE.Mesh{
      constructor(iconName, worldPosition, cameraPosition){
        super();
        this.iconName = iconName;
        this.worldPosition = worldPosition;
        this.cameraPosition = cameraPosition;
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );     
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );   
        console.log(this.mesh); // Error: undefined
      }
    };
...

scene.add(obj.mesh);
// Error: THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.
```

Comment: Why would you *want* to create a `new THREE.Mesh(…)` inside the constructor for an instance that already is a mesh (through inheritance)? It looks like you either don't want inheritance at all, favouring composition and having the `.mesh` as a property of your `Icon` object, or that you should be calling `super( geometry, material );`

Comment: Thank you pointing that out!  ```class Icon extends THREE.Mesh{
      constructor(iconName, worldPosition, cameraPosition, colour){
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: colour } );  
        let mesh = super(geometry, material ); 
        scene.add(mesh);  
      }```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct class would look like so:

```js
class Icon extends THREE.Mesh{
  constructor(iconName, worldPosition, cameraPosition){
    super();
    this.iconName = iconName;
    this.worldPosition = worldPosition;
    this.cameraPosition = cameraPosition;
    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );     
    console.log(this);
  }
};
```

Instead of creating a new instance of `Mesh`, the idea is to just assign the new geometry and material to the existing properties `geometry` and `material`.